# Python While loop won't exit when asked to

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't understand why when the user enters "0" the loop won't exit.

```
def floatInput():
    done = False
    while not done:
        integerIn = input("Please enter an integer < 0 to finish >: ")
        try:
            integerIn = int(integerIn)            
        except:
            print("I was expecting an integer number, please try again...")
            import sys
            sys.exit()
        if integerIn == "0":
           done = True
        else:
            integers.append(integerIn)
    return integers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def floatInput():
    done = False
    while not done:
        integerIn = input("Please enter an integer < 0 to finish >: ")
        try:
            integerIn = int(integerIn)            
        except:
            print("I was expecting an integer number, please try again...")
            import sys
            sys.exit()
```

Everything above here is fine, but as soon as you got to the comparison, you forgot that you've casted the input to an int.

```
if integerIn == "0":
```

Should be

```
if integerIn == 0:
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because `integerIn` is an integer and you are treating it like a string in `if integerIn=="0"`. Replace it with `integerIN==0` will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You're converting to an integer and then checking for equality with the string "0".

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if integerIn == 0:
```

should work now.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** screw the advice about using `input` or `raw_input`. Just saw you python 3.x tag, but decided to leave it for future readers.

You have few problems there...

First, in this line:

```
integers.append(integerIn)
```

where is `integers` to begin with? unless it's a global name you must define it in your function.

Second, in this line:

```
if integerIn == "0":
```

you're comparing integer to string here, and here's a thing: in python (using python 2.7 here) a *string will be bigger than any number* if you're doing a comparison, so `integerIn == "0"` will evaluate to `False`, always.

Fix it with this:

```
if integerIn == 0:
```

Finally, I should tell you this... your code the way it looks like will throws `NameError` instead of executing what you've done in your `except` statement.

Try it with the following test cases and try to explain the behavior yourself :)

```
Please enter an integer < 0 to finish >: test
Please enter an integer < 0 to finish >: "test"
```

To avoid such problem next time, use `raw_input` instead of `input`. So this line:

```
integerIn = input("Please enter an integer < 0 to finish >: ")
```

should be like this:

```
integerIn = raw_input("Please enter an integer < 0 to finish >: ")
```

NOTICE: I'm not sure but I think `raw_input` doesn't exist in python 3.x, instead `input` there will do exactly the same. please correct if I'm wrong.
However, If you're using python 3 then I think you should have no problem.

Here's `input` vs `raw_input()` in python 2.x:

`input` will *evaluate* the user input then return it.

`raw_input` will return the user input as string.

so:

```
# python 2.x
foo = input("input something")     # input 3 + 5
print foo                          # prints 8

bar = raw_input("input something") # input 3 + 5
print bar                          # prints "3 + 5"
```